# Calculate team placement in a league table in the previous match day

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recreational-mathematics

There are 14 teams in my online soccer manager league. The league tracks what direction a team moved after its previous match result and tracks its current location. I am wondering if, given only this information, I can calculate what the standings were before any team played its games that day. I think that, with the right combinations of matches and results, it is possible, but is it possible given any random matches and results? What about with random matches but non-random results?

I attempted calculating the standings of the league table before any team played a match (the league table is released about 3 hours before the first match and about 8 hours before the final match). My league table had 8 teams move up, 4 teams move down, and 2 teams stay put. 2 teams tied and the rest won/lost.
Here is a table to represent all of the standings and movement:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
Rank & Mov. & Name & Opp.  \\ \hline
1 & up & P & N  \\ \hline
2 & up & Sk & Fi \\ \hline
3 & up & L & B \\ \hline
4 & down & G & U \\ \hline
5 & up & M & O  \\ \hline
6 & down & Su & Fe  \\ \hline
7 & up & Sc & V  \\ \hline
8 & stay & V & Sc  \\ \hline
9 & up & Fe & Su  \\ \hline
10 & up & O & M  \\ \hline
11 & up & U & G  \\ \hline
12 & stay & B & L  \\ \hline
13 & down & Fi & Sk  \\ \hline
14 & down & N & P \\ \hline
\end{array}

Keep in mind the names are just the first (plus 2nd in some cases) letter of the team's names. Given the two teams who stayed in place and the each teams' movements along with their opponents, is there a mathematical way to figure out where each team started from here. With a little guessing and attempting at remembering the starting places (I did take a glance at the starting ranks about an hour before the first match was played) I came up with this:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
Rank & Name  \\ \hline
1 & N  \\ \hline
2 & P  \\ \hline
3 & G  \\ \hline
4 & Su  \\ \hline
5 & Sk  \\ \hline
6 & M  \\ \hline
7 & Fi  \\ \hline
8 & V  \\ \hline
9 & Sc  \\ \hline
10 & L  \\ \hline
11 & F  \\ \hline
12 & B  \\ \hline
13 & O  \\ \hline
14 & U  \\ \hline
\end{array}

I used Teams $V$, $B$, and $O$ as references because two did not move and one I seem to remember at #13. The first team I went to solve for was $G$ because of the limited possibilities it had (#1, 2, or 3). Also, I gave myself the rule that there was some sort of convoluted algorithm working out each individual week so that no team would play another more than once. Working out the sum of every pair's rank gave: $3, 3, 15, 15, 19, 19, 17, 17, 17, 17, 15, 15, 19, 19$ and calculating the differences between a team's sum and the sum of the team directly underneath it in the starter table gives the result: $12, 0, 4, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 4$. Removing the 0's, we get a clean $12, 4, -2, 0, -2, 4$. Expounding the table to include two more teams (#15 and #16) who play each other add the difference of 12 to the end of what is above.

*I hope this is clear enough to read and work with as at points I even confused myself and had to explain myself and reword to clarify something. I also do not know what field of mathematics this would fit under so I couldn't put any tags.*
* Just as a note, I am only doing this to attempt to create a more comprehensive league generator / bracket generator with a learning algorithm. This would be one algorithm as a starter for the generator to work from.

Comment: After a complete set of matches (each team plays exactly one other team), how far can the rank of a team change? And what is the rule for rank change?

Comment: @quasi it can change as much as it wants because it is determined by points in relation to all other teams. (A win is +3, a tie +1, a loss = no change)

Comment: So you know all the change directions, and you know the new rankings. The question is whether you can infer the previous rankings, yes?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Do you know the current point totals, or only the ranking?

Comment: You know the current point totals as well. I didn't post them however. If you need, the point totals (in order) are 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.

Comment: So you know who played who and you know the outcome of each match, yes? That means you know the change in total points, but presumably, you don't know the totals, else you could subtract to get the prior rankings.

Comment: Just for clarification, I know who played who, the score,  and what players scored each goal, which I don't think is relevant. I also know each teams total goals for, against, matches played, and league points.

Comment: But if you know league point totals, why can't you just subtract to get the prior totals, and hence the prior rankings?

Comment: Because this is after the first day, when everyone had 0 points.

Comment: If everyone had zero points on the previous day, what determines the prior ranking?

Comment: That is somewhat I am trying to determine: is there a way to determine the prior day's rankings? If so, there is probably a sort of algorithm to determine rankings and matches.

Comment: If there were rankings for the prior day, there must have been point totals. In other words, the point totals for the prior day are not all zero. Rather, you don't know them. All you know is the outcome of the current day's matches, and you know the new rankings.

Comment: The point totals for the previous day was either 0 or just rounded to 0.

Comment: If the point totals (season totals) for the previous day were all zero, then on the previous day, all teams would have the same rank.

Comment: That should be true, yes, but they still do have different ranks visually.

Comment: Visually? What does that mean? If ranks are determined by season point totals, then such totals exist, even if you don't know them. And those season totals can't all be zero, else all teams would have the same rank.

Comment: OMG thank you @quasi for your questions!  It seems the OP is trying to ask this: Even before the first match, i.e. when every team has $0$ goals, $0$ wins, $0$ losses and $0$ draws, nevertheless the league table has a ranking of the teams.  Nobody knows what the ranking is based on (Previous season results?  Alphabetically by first name of manager?  Time of registering the team?  Pundits' predictions?) but the OP is asking: Can we at least figure out what the heck was the previous ranking, i.e. the "pre-season" ranking?

Comment: @antkam: Thanks for trying to help clarify, but I still don't really understand, so I'll let someone else take over now. Should I delete all my comments?

Comment: @quasi - Please do NOT delete your comments!  They bring much clarity to what the OP may or may not be trying to do.  :)

Comment: @antkam that is exactly what I am trying to ask.